# How to merge multiple arrays and change all duplicated key into unique key?

Tags: php

I am using php recursive function to merge multiple arrays by `$test = array_merge((array)$test, $new_sum2); print_r ($test);`

Output as below :

```
Array ( [0] => 0 ) 
Array ( 
[0] => 0 
[1] => Array ( [package_amount] => 1500.00 [first_name] => Chan Li Ching [created_on] => 2020-02-16 18:33:26 ) 
[2] => Array ( [package_amount] => 1500.00 [first_name] => KOH YEEN FONG [created_on] => 2020-02-16 18:41:45 ) ) 
Array ( 
[0] => 0 
[1] => Array ( [package_amount] => 1500.00 [first_name] => Chan Li Ching [created_on] => 2020-02-16 18:33:26 ) )

Array ( 
[0] => 0 
[1] => Array ( [package_amount] => 7500.00 [first_name] => Teh Kok Leng [created_on] => 2020-02-14 13:28:12 ) 
[2] => Array ( [package_amount] => 7500.00 [first_name] => Choo Lee Chan [created_on] => 2020-02-14 13:30:17 ) 
[3] => Array ( [package_amount] => 3000.00 [first_name] => Azmi Abdul Wahab [created_on] => 2020-02-12 11:30:02 ) 
[4] => Array ( [package_amount] => 19500.00 [first_name] => Endah Korniawati Binti Md. Ali [created_on] => 2020-02-12 11:30:02 ) ) 

Array ( 
[0] => 0 
[1] => Array ( [package_amount] => 7500.00 [first_name] => Teh Kok Leng [created_on] => 2020-02-14 13:28:12 ) 
[2] => Array ( [package_amount] => 7500.00 [first_name] => Choo Lee Chan [created_on] => 2020-02-14 13:30:17 ) 
[3] => Array ( [package_amount] => 3000.00 [first_name] => Azmi Abdul Wahab [created_on] => 2020-02-12 11:30:02 ) 
[4] => Array ( [package_amount] => 3000.00 [first_name] => Lim Khee Yaw [created_on] => 2020-02-12 11:30:02 ) 
[5] => Array ( [package_amount] => 1500.00 [first_name] => Won Ku Fatt@Wah Kai Fatt [created_on] => 2020-02-12 11:30:02 ) 
[6] => Array ( [package_amount] => 1500.00 [first_name] => Tan Kam [created_on] => 2020-02-12 11:30:02 ) 
[7] => Array ( [package_amount] => 3000.00 [first_name] => Tee Siew khim [created_on] => 2020-02-12 11:30:02 ) 
[8] => Array ( [package_amount] => 1500.00 [first_name] => Tan Yi Fu [created_on] => 2020-02-12 11:30:02 ) )
```

how to combine multiple array into 1 array and make sure all key is unique increment?

Below is output of var_export() :

```
array ( 0 => 0, )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Chan Li Ching', 'created_on' => '2020-02-16 18:33:26', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'KOH YEEN FONG', 'created_on' => '2020-02-16 18:41:45', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Chan Li Ching', 'created_on' => '2020-02-16 18:33:26', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Choo Lee Chan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:30:17', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '3000.00', 'first_name' => 'Azmi Abdul Wahab', 'created_on' => '2020-02-12 11:30:02', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '19500.00', 'first_name' => 'Endah Korniawati Binti Md. Ali', 'created_on' => '2020-02-12 11:30:02', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Choo Lee Chan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:30:17', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '3000.00', 'first_name' => 'Azmi Abdul Wahab', 'created_on' => '2020-02-12 11:30:02', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '3000.00', 'first_name' => 'Lim Khee Yaw', 'created_on' => '2020-02-12 11:30:02', ), 5 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Won Ku Fatt@Wah Kai Fatt', 'created_on' => '2020-02-12 11:30:02', ), 6 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Tan Kam', 'created_on' => '2020-02-12 11:30:02', ), 7 => array ( 'package_amount' => '3000.00', 'first_name' => 'Tee Siew khim', 'created_on' => '2020-02-12 11:30:02', ), 8 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Tan Yi Fu', 'created_on' => '2020-02-12 11:30:02', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Choo Lee Chan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:30:17', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '3000.00', 'first_name' => 'Azmi Abdul Wahab', 'created_on' => '2020-02-12 11:30:02', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '3000.00', 'first_name' => 'Lim Khee Yaw', 'created_on' => '2020-02-12 11:30:02', ), 5 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Won Ku Fatt@Wah Kai Fatt', 'created_on' => '2020-02-12 11:30:02', ), 6 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Tan Kam', 'created_on' => '2020-02-12 11:30:02', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Choo Lee Chan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:30:17', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '3000.00', 'first_name' => 'Azmi Abdul Wahab', 'created_on' => '2020-02-12 11:30:02', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '3000.00', 'first_name' => 'Lim Khee Yaw', 'created_on' => '2020-02-12 11:30:02', ), 5 => array ( 'package_amount' => '300.00', 'first_name' => 'Cheong Choke Fei', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 14:01:09', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Choo Lee Chan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:30:17', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Choo Lee Chan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:30:17', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Ang Sen Lai', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:23:20', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'NG Kim Nerng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 01:33:08', ), 5 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Tan Hua Sai', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 01:36:00', ), 6 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Koh kim Lian', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 01:38:23', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Choo Lee Chan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:30:17', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Ang Sen Lai', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:23:20', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'NG Kim Nerng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 01:33:08', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Choo Lee Chan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:30:17', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Choo Lee Chan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:30:17', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Choo Lee Chan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:30:17', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Choo Lee Chan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:30:17', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Tan Thian Siew', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 01:37:11', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Loh Kong Seng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:31:21', ), 5 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Tan Poh Kok', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 01:40:23', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Choo Lee Chan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:30:17', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Tan Thian Siew', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 01:37:11', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Loh Kong Seng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:31:21', ), 5 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Tan Poh Kok', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 01:40:23', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Choo Lee Chan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:30:17', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Tan Thian Siew', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 01:37:11', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Loh Kong Seng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:31:21', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Choo Lee Chan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:30:17', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Tan Thian Siew', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 01:37:11', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Loh Kong Seng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:31:21', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Choo Lee Chan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:30:17', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Tan Thian Siew', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 01:37:11', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Loh Kong Seng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:31:21', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Choo Lee Chan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:30:17', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Tan Thian Siew', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 01:37:11', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Lam Yet Lan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 02:18:28', ), 5 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Tai Kwee Mei', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:37:25', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Choo Lee Chan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:30:17', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Tan Thian Siew', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 01:37:11', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Lam Yet Lan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 02:18:28', ), 5 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Tai Kwee Mei', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:37:25', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Choo Lee Chan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:30:17', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Tan Thian Siew', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 01:37:11', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Lam Yet Lan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 02:18:28', ), 5 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Yew Kok geow', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:32:29', ), 6 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'KUAN CHIEN CHING', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:35:18', ), 7 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Kong Voon Sze', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 01:44:12', ), 8 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Tan Chuan Hock', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 01:41:36', ), 9 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'LEE TECK GUAN', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 02:19:38', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Choo Lee Chan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:30:17', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Tan Thian Siew', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 01:37:11', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Lam Yet Lan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 02:18:28', ), 5 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Yew Kok geow', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:32:29', ), 6 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'KUAN CHIEN CHING', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:35:18', ), 7 => array ( 'package_amount' => '100.00', 'first_name' => 'HENG JIA CHUAN', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:36:27', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Choo Lee Chan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:30:17', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Tan Thian Siew', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 01:37:11', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Lam Yet Lan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 02:18:28', ), 5 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Yew Kok geow', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:32:29', ), 6 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'KUAN CHIEN CHING', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:35:18', ), 7 => array ( 'package_amount' => '100.00', 'first_name' => 'HENG JIA CHUAN', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:36:27', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Choo Lee Chan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:30:17', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Tan Thian Siew', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 01:37:11', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Lam Yet Lan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 02:18:28', ), 5 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Yew Kok geow', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:32:29', ), 6 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'KUAN CHIEN CHING', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:35:18', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Choo Lee Chan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:30:17', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Tan Thian Siew', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 01:37:11', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Lam Yet Lan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 02:18:28', ), 5 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Yew Kok geow', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:32:29', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Choo Lee Chan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:30:17', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Tan Thian Siew', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 01:37:11', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Lam Yet Lan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 02:18:28', ), 5 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Yew Kok geow', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:32:29', ), 6 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Maniwanan', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:26:44', ), 7 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Ahmad Bin Kardi', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:25:23', ), 8 => array ( 'package_amount' => '3000.00', 'first_name' => 'Nge Ah Chai', 'created_on' => '2020-02-17 17:46:01', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '200.00', 'first_name' => 'Heng Li Hooi', 'created_on' => '2020-02-22 14:14:30', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teoh Soon Nien', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 23:08:13', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1000.00', 'first_name' => 'Teoh Soon Nien', 'created_on' => '2020-02-24 18:55:01', ), 5 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Tan Seng Yip', 'created_on' => '2020-02-17 17:49:47', ), 6 => array ( 'package_amount' => '100.00', 'first_name' => 'Ng Sze Hui', 'created_on' => '2020-02-29 23:41:08', ), 7 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1400.00', 'first_name' => 'Ng Sze Hui', 'created_on' => '2020-02-29 12:03:27', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '200.00', 'first_name' => 'Heng Li Hooi', 'created_on' => '2020-02-22 14:14:30', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teoh Soon Nien', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 23:08:13', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1000.00', 'first_name' => 'Teoh Soon Nien', 'created_on' => '2020-02-24 18:55:01', ), 5 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Tan Seng Yip', 'created_on' => '2020-02-17 17:49:47', ), 6 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Lim Beng Choo', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 23:36:16', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '200.00', 'first_name' => 'Heng Li Hooi', 'created_on' => '2020-02-22 14:14:30', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teoh Soon Nien', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 23:08:13', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1000.00', 'first_name' => 'Teoh Soon Nien', 'created_on' => '2020-02-24 18:55:01', ), 5 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Ng Yong Kuang', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 16:12:11', ), 6 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Ng Yong Kim', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 16:14:25', ), 7 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Ong Chun Tat', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 22:47:08', ), 8 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Cheng Sai Tik', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 23:10:46', ), 9 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'CHEW YIAW XIN', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 22:50:24', ), 10 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1000.00', 'first_name' => 'PUNG PEI WEN', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 23:03:17', ), 11 => array ( 'package_amount' => '500.00', 'first_name' => 'Ho hwa shing', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 23:34:12', ), 12 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1000.00', 'first_name' => 'Bu Yong Khang', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 23:25:54', ), 13 => array ( 'package_amount' => '100.00', 'first_name' => 'Yeap Chun Hong', 'created_on' => '2020-02-16 23:58:03', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '200.00', 'first_name' => 'Heng Li Hooi', 'created_on' => '2020-02-22 14:14:30', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teoh Soon Nien', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 23:08:13', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1000.00', 'first_name' => 'Teoh Soon Nien', 'created_on' => '2020-02-24 18:55:01', ), 5 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Ng Yong Kuang', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 16:12:11', ), 6 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Ng Yong Kim', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 16:14:25', ), 7 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Ong Chun Tat', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 22:47:08', ), 8 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Cheng Sai Tik', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 23:10:46', ), 9 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'CHEW YIAW XIN', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 22:50:24', ), 10 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1000.00', 'first_name' => 'PUNG PEI WEN', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 23:03:17', ), 11 => array ( 'package_amount' => '500.00', 'first_name' => 'Ho hwa shing', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 23:34:12', ), 12 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1000.00', 'first_name' => 'Bu Yong Khang', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 23:25:54', ), 13 => array ( 'package_amount' => '600.00', 'first_name' => 'Ong chun wei', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 23:28:34', ), 14 => array ( 'package_amount' => '100.00', 'first_name' => 'TEH SOON POH', 'created_on' => '2020-02-16 23:58:47', ), 15 => array ( 'package_amount' => '2000.00', 'first_name' => 'WONG KOK YIN', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 23:12:07', ), 16 => array ( 'package_amount' => '200.00', 'first_name' => 'HO HU GEE', 'created_on' => '2020-02-16 23:58:03', ), 17 => array ( 'package_amount' => '100.00', 'first_name' => 'TEH TIEK KEAN', 'created_on' => '2020-02-16 23:58:03', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '200.00', 'first_name' => 'Heng Li Hooi', 'created_on' => '2020-02-22 14:14:30', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teoh Soon Nien', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 23:08:13', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1000.00', 'first_name' => 'Teoh Soon Nien', 'created_on' => '2020-02-24 18:55:01', ), 5 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Ng Yong Kuang', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 16:12:11', ), 6 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Ng Yong Kim', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 16:14:25', ), 7 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Ong Chun Tat', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 22:47:08', ), 8 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Lim Wei hang', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 16:13:16', ), 9 => array ( 'package_amount' => '400.00', 'first_name' => 'Chong san lee', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 22:58:43', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '200.00', 'first_name' => 'Heng Li Hooi', 'created_on' => '2020-02-22 14:14:30', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teoh Soon Nien', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 23:08:13', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1000.00', 'first_name' => 'Teoh Soon Nien', 'created_on' => '2020-02-24 18:55:01', ), 5 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1500.00', 'first_name' => 'Ng Yong Kuang', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 16:12:11', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '200.00', 'first_name' => 'Heng Li Hooi', 'created_on' => '2020-02-22 14:14:30', ), 3 => array ( 'package_amount' => '500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teoh Soon Nien', 'created_on' => '2020-02-15 23:08:13', ), 4 => array ( 'package_amount' => '1000.00', 'first_name' => 'Teoh Soon Nien', 'created_on' => '2020-02-24 18:55:01', ), )array ( 0 => 0, 1 => array ( 'package_amount' => '7500.00', 'first_name' => 'Teh Kok Leng', 'created_on' => '2020-02-14 13:28:12', ), 2 => array ( 'package_amount' => '200.00', 'first_name' => 'Heng Li Hooi', 'created_on' => '2020-02-22 14:14:30', ), )
```

Comment: Merge as in flatten them into a single array? Can you share a var_export() of your array? How deep can be the values?

Comment: can you show what `var_export()` gives instead of print_r() so others can play around with it?

Comment: Ok I have adding var_export() on my question description. Please check it. Thank you.

Comment: @zac1987 Don't do individual var_export(). Share the entire var_export() of the whole array once.

Comment: @vivek_23 ok i have update my question as your request, please check it. Thank you.

Comment: @zac1987 It's still the same. var_export() allows us to directly get your array in correct syntactical format which I can use. If you just copy paste this, you will realize it isn't a correctly formed array. I think you are var exporting in a loop or in a recursive way. Don't do that. Just var_export() the array which contains the entire information and paste it in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm getting it correctly you can use `array_merge` function to merge all this arrays into one. As the doc says if the array index are numbers the result array keys will be renumbered with incrementing.

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
>   for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays
>   contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original
>   value, but will be appended.
>
> **Values in the input arrays with numeric keys will be renumbered with
>   incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.**

Example:

```
php > $a = [0 => 'a', 1 => 'b'];
php > $b = [0 => 'c', 1 => 'd'];

php > print_r(array_merge($a, $b));
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
)
```

[array_merge doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: i am using array_merge but yet i get output as shown on my question. 

`function recursive5($test){
 for (i=0, i < 5, i++)
 {
  $test = array_merge((array)$test, $new_sum2);
  recursive5($test);
  i = i + 1;
 }
}`

Comment: Ok, so to clear up things. You are acumulating into an array some indexed arrays with some person/user data. I assume that you are printing inside a loop/recursion and printing, so each array in your posted output is the accumulated data in an interation. Is that correct? If so the last array in your output should be the final result.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the guidance